# Reduce objects in a 2d array to a single property and assign new static keys

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have an array mind

```
[{"id":"331","file_name":"3b1379e2496408dd4c865f5f63f96bf6","file_path":"https://path/3b1379e2496408dd4c865f5f63f96bf6.png"},
{"id":"332","file_name":"d0ef559473a061086592bceed0880a01","file_path":"https://path/d0ef559473a061086592bceed0880a01.png"}]
```

I need to output this array so that in the end it looks like this

```
[{url:"https://path/3b1379e2496408dd4c865f5f63f96bf6.png"},
{url:"https://path/d0ef559473a061086592bceed0880a01.png"}]
```

To output only one field from an array, I use

```
array_column($array, 'file_path')
```

And I end up with

```
["https://path/3b1379e2496408dd4c865f5f63f96bf6.png",
"https://path/d0ef559473a061086592bceed0880a01.png"]
```

But how now to make these fields be objects and add a url in front of them?

Comment: `array_map(fn($value) => (object) ['url' => $value], array_column($array, 'file_path'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dirt-basic version - simply loop through the array and make a new one with just the property you want in each entry:

```
$json = '[{"id":"331","file_name":"3b1379e2496408dd4c865f5f63f96bf6","file_path":"https://path/3b1379e2496408dd4c865f5f63f96bf6.png"},
{"id":"332","file_name":"d0ef559473a061086592bceed0880a01","file_path":"https://path/d0ef559473a061086592bceed0880a01.png"}]';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$output = [];

foreach ($arr as $item)
{
    $output[] = ["url" => $item["file_path"]];
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/JcKZE

---

Or for a slick one-liner, make use of the `array_map` function:

In the above, replace the `$output = [];` and the `foreach` loop with:

```
$output = array_map(fn($value) => (object) ['url' => $value], array_column($arr, 'file_path'));
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/a10kB

Comment: Is there anything you can do with links like this? `"https:\/\/path\/3b1379e2496408dd4c865f5f63f96bf6.png"` I mean to usually output `"https://path/.."`

Comment: @Hector There's a `json_encode()` flag for that, `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`, that omits the slashes.

Comment: ...but you shouldn't need to worry about it, because a decent JSON parser decoding that data would understand, and remove the slashes again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapping operation:

```
array_map(
    fn($value) => (object) ['url' => $value],
    array_column($array, 'file_path')
)
```

https://3v4l.org/vbguH

For 7.3 and below (no arrow function support):

```
array_map(
    function($value) {
        return (object) ['url' => $value];
    },
    array_column($array, 'file_path')
)
```

Note, unless you want object syntax or features in PHP (`$foo->url`), you can omit the `(object)` casting; it will still JSON encode with object syntax unless you tell it not to.

Comment: I get an error `syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: It's a PHP version thing. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `array_column()` AND `array_map()` is performing unnecessary cycles -- don't call `array_column()` at all.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ha8fJ))

```
echo json_encode(
         array_map(
             fn($obj) => ['url' => $obj->file_name],
             json_decode($json)
         )
     );
```

Or if you want get cute with code styling, you can populate the new array data via a body-less loop and destructuring syntax. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tHckm))

```
$result = [];
foreach (json_decode($json, true) as ['file_name' => $result[]['url']]);
echo json_encode($result);
```